# Changing password of postfix user account directly in the MySQL database

Tags: mysql, postfix

I need to change a password of a postfix user account mailbox directly in a MySQL database; however I have no idea of the format used.

Here is the table:

```
SELECT username,password FROM mailbox LIMIT 1;
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| username         | password                           |
+------------------+------------------------------------+
| user@example.com | $1$60Dgu9vc$T7vaQfTKgxUpci0TTnsyO0 |
+------------------+------------------------------------+
```

What format is it? How to change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$1$` at the beginning of the password field hints it is a MD5 hash.

To encrypt a password in a MD5 hash, you can use the `openssl passwd` command.

From [man openssl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/openssl):

> passwd    Generation of hashed passwords.

and from `openssl passwd --help`:

> -1                 MD5-based password algorithm
>   -stdin             read passwords from stdin

So to generate the MD5 hash, a short bash example:

```
#/bin/bash
PASSWORD="test123"
MD5=`echo $PASSWORD | openssl passwd -1 -stdin`
```

Running it, you got as output the intended encrypted password:

```
$1$EaYOC8n4$04LSDBtt4A8GPVRUkzBXG/
```

So to change the password in the MySQL DB to 'test123', you do in the MySQL prompt:

`USE postfix
UPDATE mailbox SET password="$1$EaYOC8n4$04LSDBtt4A8GPVRUkzBXG/" WHERE username="user@example.com";`

The change takes effect immediately, and the user will notice the change in the next mailbox access.